# Subselect DataFrame based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a small DataFrame object (plot_data, 800 values) which has the following columns:

- `Stimulus` (random number on each cell)
- `TrialNumber` (sequence 0-99,repeated 8 times)
- `BlockNumber` (for each `TrialNumber` sequence 0-99 there is Block 1, then 2, then 3 until 8)

**Example**:

```
Stimulus  TrialNumber BlockNumber
      45           1            1
      72           2            1
      12           3            1
     ...         ...          ...
      34          99            8
```

I would like to subselect a value from `Stimulus` based on two conditions, the value of `TrialNumber` and the value of `BlockNumber`.
So far I managed to subselect the `Stimulus` value for the position index only:

`plot_data['Stimulus'][1])` where `1` is the index

Is there a way to subselect `Stimulus` based on the index of `TrialNumber` AND the index of `BlockNumber` with the same line of code?

For example, if I wanted to subselect the `Stimulus` for `TrialNumber` 99 and `BlockNumber` 9 (which is 34 in this example), how could I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: so basically you want to iterate over each row, what the bigger problem here?

Comment: My problem is that so far I managed only to select by one condition, the TrialNumber (iteration e), but I would like to select by two conditions, TrialNumber (e) and BlockNumber (iteration i).

Comment: Please [explain your overall goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as you want to avoid `for` loops in pandas. Why do you need to iterate row by row each *stimulus* which is still your overall goal since each row will have a unique `e` and `i` iteration? Likely, there are methods to handle needs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I removed the -for- loop part as it is not important for what I need. I rewrote the question focusing on the indexing part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created an example dataframe just like your above df

```
data = {'Stimulus': [45, 72, 12, 34],
        'TrialNumber': [1, 2, 3, 99],
        'BlockNumber': [1, 1, 1, 8]}
```

If you want to select a column value based on multiple conditions, you could it like the following :

```
df.loc[(df['TrialNumber'] == 99) &
              (df['BlockNumber'] == 8)]['Stimulus'].values[0]
```

This would give you the Stimulus value **34**

Comment: I tried to run your code but it does not seem to work

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: are you using python3 ?

Comment: Now check it again